# Lock screen - more time to switch off monitor

Tags: lock-screen

When I lock my screen, Ubuntu switches off my monitor after one minute. How can I set longer a time for it?

Edit: I mean: when i use Alt+Ctrl+L, my computer is locked, I want to see my lock-out picture for longer time than 1 minute. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 2):

You can open **System Settings** then click on **Brightness and Screen Lock**.

You can change the value from the drop-down:

**Turn screen off when inactive for:** [Time value dropdown]

[image]